# how can i programmatically set a python breakpoint in visual studio code on Macos

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

That is, in my Python3 code on MacOS, is there some Python command I can put in my code to cause a breakpoint in Visual Studio Code?

I believe in Java they use "debugger" for this.

Comment: what is the problem hitting F9 on the same line

Comment: you mean something like `breakpoint()`?

Answer (score 0):

After python3.7 you can use `breakpoint()` to insert breakpoints in your code.

```py
x = 10
y = 20
z = x + y

breakpoint()

result = z * 2
print(result)
```

In vscode you can insert breakpoints directly by clicking on the front of a line of code.

[image]

Regarding debugging, you can also configure *[launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_additional-configurations)* to define more parameters.